# Can't get React Router's 4 Link working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

Here is the code of component where problem occurs:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Redirect, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
    import * as actions from 'actions';

    class DashBoard extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.dispatch(actions.deleteItems());
            this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchItems());
        }
        render() {
            let { items } = this.props;
            let key = 0;
            let renderItems = () => {
                if (!items) {
                    return
                }
                return items.map((item) => {
                    let { action, author } = item.logs[item.logs.length - 1];
                    return (
                        <div className="dashboard-item">
                            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                            <div className="info-container">
                                <span>Amount: {item.number}</span>
                                <span>{item.state}</span>
                            </div>
                            <span className="created">{`${action} by ${author}`}</span>
                            <span className="last-log">{`Last log: ${item.logs[0].action} by ${item.logs[0].author}`}</span>
                            <div className="buttons">
                                <Link to='/'>Edit</Link>
                                <Link to={`/items/${item.id}/edit`}>Delete</Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }

            if (this.props.auth.token) {
                return (
                    <div className="dashboard-container">
                        {renderItems()}
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(actions.setError('You must log in.'))
                return <Redirect to='/' />
            }
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(connect(
        (state) => {
            return state;
        }

)(DashBoard));
```

I got Redirect working, but clicking a link just changes url in browser, and actually I still see my dashboard component. If I enter localhost:3000/items/*random id*/edit i get right result. Creating and clicking a link does nothing. Nothing changes visually except url bar. withRouter hack seems to not work for me. However entering url directly works. How can I fix this?

EDIT : Route definition

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Home from 'Home';
import Dashboard from 'Dashboard';
import EditItemForm from 'EditItemForm';
import NewItemForm from 'NewItemForm';

export class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let { auth, error } = this.props;
        let renderError = () => {
            if (error) {
                return (
                    <div className="error">
                        <p>{error}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            } else {
                return (<div></div>)
            }
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {renderError()}
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/items/:id/edit" component={EditItemForm} />
                <Route path="/items/new" component={NewItemForm}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return state;
    }
)(Main);
```

EDIT #2: Figured out that clicking a Link even doesnt change pathname in route > location > pathname if look into React DevTools

Comment: Did you check if there are more than just one route matching the URL? If you are coming from React-Router v3.x, you must change the way urls are matched.

Comment: Do you use BrowserRouter or just Router?

Comment: @Syberic, I edited my post and added Main component where all routes are defined

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca, I am not sure I got what are u takling about ;(

Comment: Try puting some breakpoints on your components, I'm guessing perhaps Dashboard and Home are matching the URL, so If I'm right, you should see Home and Dashboard being rendered.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca, I put componentWillMount hook on both, and after clicking the link no one triggers. Directly typing url which I want link to work with swill works.

Comment: @RomanSarder Can you post Main/App/Base component where your Router appears please?

Comment: @RomanSarder i see no actual <Router> there, only Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just rolled back to v3. Thank you guys for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may need to use a switch above all routes in a component because even I had a similar issue before. however that works in react router v3. Hope this helps u :) cheers

[React Router 4](http://frontend.turing.io/lessons/react-router-4.html)

[React Router v4 Unofficial Migration Guide](https://medium.com/@francoisz/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a)

Comment: In newer versions of React Router there is no Match.

Comment: @RomanSarder thanks for that. I just missed the version 4 tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is nothing wrong with your code relative to the use of React Router that you shown here.

I would suggest that you simplify your application and you post the main Router component, it should be fine because you see your dashboard, but it can help.

Try to do a fake hello word route and do the transition from your dashboard to there..

Usually the most likely thing you could have here is a nested component that is blocking the update of the route. Usually putting withRouter in every connected component should work. Alternatively you could try to add withRouter in every component that is nested with the route.

I think there should be a elegant why to solve this, but maybe this can help you know where this problem comes from.

Then try to check if your third party libraries support RR4.
Good luck!